# C\C++ LINPACK source code for window free for commercial use?

Tags: c++, windows, free, benchmarking

I need run benchmark to test my cpu FLOPS and compare this with raitings such as top500 org. I known Linpack is are standart for measure CPU perfomance. But i can find source code for windows on C\C++ without not free librarys like Intel MKL library, etc Maybe someone know where i can find C\C++ LINPACK source code for window free for commercial use? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/documentation.html Isn't here enough information to run the test on your machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only official variant of Linpack that can be used for TOP500 comparison is HPL - high performance linpack.

Do you really need some code "free for commercial use?" or you can use GPL/BSD code?

There are some good linear algebras libraries BLAS (on which HPL depends to get the high performance), e.g. ATLAS, GOTOBlas. They come with source code.